# How can I get the Register form on the front page in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-theming, drupal-forms, drupal-8

I've been trying to get the create account form (register form) in a pop-up on the front page, without any success.

Can anybody here help me out with an example that works?

I've tried adapting examples from Drupal 7 but couldn't get them to work, I've tried to make a custom form but it didn't work, I've tried installing modules that could handle this but they also didn't work.

The last attempt I've made to resolve this problem was:

```
<?php

/**
* @file
* Functions to support theming in the themename theme.
*/

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\UrlHelper;

/**
* Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for HTML document templates.
*/

function themename_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\user\register');

return $form;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock which exposes some additional forms as blocks (like the user registration, new password, contact, etc..). So after you install it you can just configure the block to appear only on the front page. The registration block will not be available for authenticated users or if the anonymous users are not allowed to create new accounts.

However, you will also have to apply this patch https://www.drupal.org/node/2570221 (if it will not be already committed by the time you check it) if you use the latest Drupal8 stable version, otherwise you will get a fatal error.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.
I've stumbled upon that module, formblock, and installed it. However, after copying the files of the module in modules, and installing it from the admin, I couldn't find the block anywhere.

Could you tell me exactly where I could find the form register block? So i can add it on my front page?

Thanks.

Comment: You just have to go on the block layout page, here: admin/structure/block , click on the 'Place block' button of the region where you want to put the block (I suppose it would be "Content") and then search for the "User registration form" block.

Comment: Wow, I didn't try to place it...I just looked at the list of blocks, including the disabled ones, didn't see it and assumed it wasn't working. 

I got the error you were talking about, and first thing in the morning I'll apply the patch to see if it works.
Thank you:)

Comment: Yeah, in D8 the block layout page is a bit different, you see there only the blocks which are actually enabled in your regions. All the available blocks you see only when you click the 'Place block' button.

Answer (score 0):

This link explains how it can be used to programmatically render the login and registration forms.

http://web-tricks.org/content/how-render-user-login-form-and-user-register-form-drupal-8

For the login form

```
$form = Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm::class) ;
$render = Drupal::service('renderer');
$variables['login_form'] = $render->renderPlain($form);
```

and for register form

```
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->create(array());
$formObject = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getFormObject('user', 'register')->setEntity($entity);
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($formObject);
$variables['register_form'] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($form);
```